# Achieving multiple inheritance using Object.create()

Tags: javascript, multiple-inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm looking at methods of implementing multiple inheritance in JavaScript. I've done a lot of reading on the subject, and know there are several approaches, each with their strengths and weaknesses, but I haven't found a thorough analysis of `Object.create()`, at least not one in language that I can understand. I've done some experimenting and have come up with an approach that truly does achieve multiple inheritance using `Object.create()` (see the JSFiddle below).

https://jsfiddle.net/etymhecv/

In the above fiddle, the `p` variable is a `Person`, the `e` variable is an `Employee` (which inherits from `Person`) and `ae` is an `AlienEmployee` (which inherits from both the standalone class `Alien`, and from `Employee` (and hence `Person`)). The test `Person.isPerson(ae)` correctly detects that an `AlienEmployee` is a type of `Person`.

Can someone explain to me what disadvantages, if any, I may encounter by using the above approach?

Comment: *Uncaught TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function*. Weird.

Comment: @Marcus, it works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

> I have come up with an approach that truly does achieve multiple inheritance

Nope:

```
> var ae = AlienEmployee.create("Zeuss", "4321", "Marsodian")
| AlienEmployee.isAlienEmployee(p)
< true
> Alien.isAlien(p)
< false
```

Multiple prototypical inheritance is not possible in JavaScript, the prototype chain is always linear.

Your `create` methods do successfully employ a mixin pattern (either with `Object.create/defineProperties(…, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(…))` or with `extend`/`Object.assign`), but that's not really the dynamic inheritance we've known from `Object.create`.

Comment: Ah, you're right! It's a shame that an object's `prototype` can't be an array of objects, rather than just a single object.

Comment: @user1420752: You've chosen the wrong language for that :-) I guess you could implement something like that with ES6 Proxies, though.